# How to fix X in the nonrestoring divider output?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I made a design for a divider, but the result is wrong.

```
module div(x,y,quotient,remainder);

parameter M=4;
parameter N=4;

input [M-1:0] x;
input [N-1:0] y;

output [N-1:0] quotient;
output [M-1:0] remainder;
wire [M-1:0] rem_carry;

wire sum[M-1:0][N-1:0];
wire carry[M-1:0][N-1:0];
genvar i, j;
generate for(i=N-1; i>=0; i=i-1) begin:
unsigned_divider

if(i==N-1)
for(j=0; j<M; j=j+1) begin: first_row
if(j==0)
assign {carry[j][i],sum[j][i]}=y[i]+!x[j]+1;
assign {carry[j][i],sum[j][i]}=!x[j]+carry[j-1][i];
end
else
for(j=0; j<M;j=j+1) begin:rest_rows
if(j==0)
assign{carry[j][i],sum[j][i]}=y[i]+(x[j]^carry[M-1][i+1])+carry[M-1][i+1];
else
assign {carry[j][i],sum[j][i]}=sum[j-1][i+1]+(x[j]^carry[M-1][i+1])+carry[j-1][i];
end
end endgenerate

generate for(i=0; i<N; i=i+1)
begin:product_quotient
assign quotient[i]=carry[M-1][i];
end endgenerate

generate for(j=0;j<M;j=j+1)
begin:remainder_adjust
if(j==0)
assign{rem_carry[j],remainder[j]} = sum[j][0]+(sum[M-1][0]&x[j]);
else
assign{rem_carry[j],remainder[j]} =sum[j][0]+(sum[M-1][0]&x[j])+rem_carry[j-1];
end endgenerate
endmodule
```

and testbench simulation code

```
module tb_div();

parameter M = 4; // default divisor width
parameter N = 4; // default dividend width

reg [M-1:0] x;
reg [N-1:0] y;
wire[N-1:0] quotient;
wire[M-1:0] remainder;
wire[M-1:0] rem_carry;

div U0(.x(x), .y(y), .quotient(quotient), .remainder(remainder));

initial begin


    x = 0;  y = 0; 
    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;

    // Add stimulus here
    x=4'b0001;y=4'b0000;
    #300 x=4'b0100;y=4'b0011;
    #300 x=4'b1101;y=4'b1010;
    #300 x=4'b1110;y=4'b1001;
    #300 x=4'b1111;y=4'b1010;

end

endmodule
```

[image]

But, `quotient`, `remainder`, `rem_carry` is not value.

How to change the code? I think testbench is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The X values on `quotient` and `remainder` are due to contention on `carry` and `sum` in the design.  Change:

```
assign {carry[j][i],sum[j][i]}=!x[j]+carry[j-1][i];
```

to:

```
else assign {carry[j][i],sum[j][i]}=!x[j]+carry[j-1][i];
```

The missing `else` caused `carry` to be simultaneously driven by 2 `assign` statements.  The same goes for `sum`.  My simulators gave me a "part-select index out of declared bounds" compile warning on that line.  Proper indentation would have made it easier to catch this bug.

---

You get Z on the `rem_carry` signal in the testbench because the signal is undriven.  You need to add an `output` port to the `div` module and make the proper connection in the testbench.